# regex basic; prevent outer punctuation

Tags: regex

Let's say I've got a regular expression for zip code.

```
'\<[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?\>'
```

This works on:

```
XXXXX
XXXXX-XXXX
```

But it also matches on the numbers on:

```
XXXX-
.XXXX-
```

What do I use to prevent this from occurring?

Comment: What programming language/regex engine are you using?

Comment: Your regex won't match those last 2 numbers. How did you test it?

Comment: What are those `\<` and `\>` good for?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) your match from the start to the end of the string, else it will also try to match parts of the input:

```
'^\<[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?\>$'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify that this string has to be the beginning and the end of it. Simply add the `^` to indicate the beginning of the line and the `$` to indicate the end of the line.

So the result will be: (assuming that the `\<` and `\>` are needed for your language or something).

```
'\<^[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?$\>'
```

Comment: \< and \> mark the beginning and end of the word.  I've already noted that the above doesn't work on:
    
    adfsfds xxxxx sfasdsdf
    sadfds xxxxx-xxxx kdkdk

Answer (score 0):

This is the original poster.

```
'^\<[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?\>$'
```

and

```
'\<^[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?$\>'
```

don't match on lines with noise such as:

```
lskdjfasfldj  XXXXX asfsdfsdf
sdkdsa XXXXX-XXXX asdfsd
```

The two regular expressions only match at the beginning of a line, not in the middle of a line.

Also, I'm using basic regex on a Unix system with grep -E.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14856773/edit) your question if you have new information.